# Converting plist object to XML embeded in NSString

Tags: ios, xml, text, nsstring, plist

I want to send a plist object by email in an XML test format.

What kind of code (preferably simple) should I write after this one:

```
NSString *xmlString;
NSDictionary *borrowed = @{@"Reader": @"Ryan Shaw",
                           @"Books":  @[ @{@"Title":  @"The Godfather",
                                           @"Author": @"Mario Puzo",
                                           @"Date":   @"2014-04-08T13:36:33Z"},
                                         @{@"Title":  @"Adventures of Huckleberry Finn",
                                           @"Author": @"Mark Twain",
                                           @"Date":   @"2014-04-08T13:36:33Z"} ]
                         };
```

to have in result xmlString contain the following value:

```
@"<dict>
    <key>Reader</key>
    <string>Ryan Shaw</string>
    <key>Books</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>The Godfather</string>
            <key>Author</key>
            <string>Mario Puzo</string>
            <key>Date</key>
            <date>2014-04-08T13:36:33Z</date>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Adventures of Huckleberry Finn</string>
            <key>Author</key>
            <string>Mark Twain</string>
            <key>Date</key>
            <date>2014-04-08T13:36:33Z</date>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>"
```

Is there any iOS framework able to do this, or should I write the parser myself or use a third party library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing code is as follows:

```
    NSError *error;
    NSData *xmlData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:borrowed
                                                                 format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                                options:0
                                                                  error:&error];
    if ( !error )
        xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

There is no need for any special framework to be linked in.